# Proof of convexity in a quadratic function

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following quadratic objective function (almost variance function); where $f_n, i=1,...,n$ are $n$ function and $\overline f$ is the mean of $f_n$ for all $ i=1,...,n$

$$\min \sum(f_i(x_i)- \overline f(x))^2$$

At first I thought it is not a convex objective. So, the hessian matrixes are calculated for some examples and the results show that the determinant of the matrices are zero; however, the eigenvalues are  nonnegative (i.e $\ge 0$). I realized the function is semidefinite. Now, I think it may be a convex function but I don't know how I can proof the convexity.

Comment: (i) with respect to what is the minimisation carried out? is it wrt $x_i$? (ii) you mentioned that $\bar{f}$ is the expectation of $f_n$; shouldn't it be $\bar{f}_n$? (iii) expectation with respect to what? What exactly is random here? (iv) if randomness is involved, aren't $f_i(x_i)$ random variables? and, if so, shouldn't there is an expectation operator (or other operator, e.g., a risk measure)  in your cost function?

Comment: Thank you PantelisSopasakis for your reply! $x_i$ are decision variables that they are not random. The model is a deterministic model not stochastic one. $\overline f_n(x_i)$ is correct your right !

Comment: Do you then mean that for $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, it is $\bar{f}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$? In any case, could you please update your question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your problem is not convex unless you assume something about your functions $f_i$ (given that the minimisation is with respect to $x_i$). If, however, $f_i$ are linear functions, i.e.,

$$
f_i(x_i) = c_i'x_i + d_i,
$$

then,

$$
\bar{f}(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i x_i + d_i
$$

and the cost function becomes the square of a linear function

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(c_i x_i + d_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_j x_j + d_j \right)^2,
$$

which is convex.

However, in general, this cost function may not be convex. Take for example $f_i(x_i) = \sin(x_i)$.

There is a little trick one may consider using here. If $f_i$ are invertible and $f_i^{-1}$ is known or can be computed, then we can replace $f_i(x_i)$ with $y_i$ and then the problem becomes:

$$
\min_{y_1,\ldots, y_n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_j)^2,
$$

Then, once we have determined the optimisers $y_i^\star$, we can retrieve $x_i^\star=f_i^{-1}(y_i^\star)$.

**Note.** The square of a linear function $\phi(x) = cx + d$, where $c$ is a column vector and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, that is the function $\psi(x) = \phi(x)^2 = (cx + d)^2$, is covex. Indeed,

$$
\psi(x) = (cx+d)^2 = (cx)^2 + 2cx + d^2 = x'(c'c) x + 2cx + d^2,
$$

And notice here that $cc'\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix, therefore, $\psi$ is convex.

Comment: Actually $f_i(x_i)= x_i$ in the simple version of my problem.  How can I proof the square of a linear function is convex? Is there any theorem to proof that?

Comment: @rezi There you go then... by the way, these problems are called **least squares problems** and there are very efficient numerical methods to solve them. They are convex problems. A comprehensive presentation is provided [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~mtchu/Teaching/Lectures/MA529/chapter4.pdf) and you can also take a look a the corresponding [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

Comment: @rezi I updated my answer with a note.

Comment: @ Pantelis thank you so much! if the function is $ \phi (x)=cx-d $ , do you think the proof is  still valid or not?

Comment: @ Pantelis sorry if my question was basic! I know the sum of square function is semi definite but there is another part $2cx$ , that I am not sure does not have any effect in convexity.

Comment: @rezi In my answer, implicitly, I used [the following fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties): A continuous, twice differentiable function of several variables -- in our case $\psi(x)$ -- is convex on a convex set -- in our case $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- if and only if its Hessian matrix -- in our case $c'c$ -- is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set.

Comment: @  Pantelis, I realized that function of lest square that contains mean has several variables on it $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. In this case, we have summation of $\phi (x)= c_1x_1- (c'_1x_1+...+c'_nx_n)$ , so the $\psi(x)$ will be different. What is your idea?

Comment: @rezi I doesn't matter. If you write it down, you will see that it is a (convex) quadratic optimisation problem. If you like we continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32762/discussion-between-pantelis-sopasakis-and-rezi).

Comment: if $f(x)= \lVert Ax-b\rVert _2^2 $ = $ x'A'Ax-b'Ax-x'A'b+ \lVert b\rVert _2^2 $.because for any vector $x$, $x'(A'A)x=\lVert Ax\rVert _2^2 \ge 0 $; therefore, $f(x)$ is convex.\\ 
 Suppose that $i=1,2,3$ then $ \psi (x) = min \sum_{ i=1}^ {3}(x_i-\frac{\sum_{ j=1}^ {3}x_j}{3})^2$
 
$\psi (x) = (x_1-(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}))^2+(x_2-(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}))^2+(x_3-(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}))^2$

 $\psi (x) = \frac{2}{3}(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_1x_2-x_1x_3-x_2x_3)$
  
  In this case we have quadratic form of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and multipication of $x_ix_j$.